# IPsec VPN with subnet overlapping and NAT

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, openswan

I'm trying to configure, through **OpenSwan** on a `Linux Ubuntu 14.04` the following scenario.
It's an interesting configuration and it would be great to understand why I'm failing configuring correctly, even because it can help many people resolving this issue (Internet is plenty of questions about it and "half" answers).

**SCENARIO**

```
[L-App Server]<=>[L-VPN GW]<====>[R-VPN GW]<=>[NAT]<=>[R-App Server]
```

- `[L-VPN GW]` is my VPN Gateway with *Public-IP* `1.1.1.1` and *Private-IP* `10.1.1.1` and is into the ***Left-Subnet*** `10.0.0.0/8`, even with the `[L-App Server]`
- `[R-VPN GW]` is VPN Gateway of other side with *Public-IP* `2.2.2.2`. I have to reach a `[R-App Server]` with address `10.2.2.2` and ***Right-Subnet*** `10.0.0.0/8`, connected to a `NAT` with address `45.2.2.2/32` (not publicly reachable, but only reachable after tunnel instauration).

**PROBLEM**
As you can see, both `Left Subnet` and `Right Subnet` are the same. So, when I try to (for example) `ping 10.2.2.2` from my `L-VPN GW`, requests are not forwarded through the VPN tunnel, but through the LAN.
Also, I cannot see an `ipsec0` interface, in such a way I could `route` the traffic to `10.2.2.2` through that interface (even if I don't thing it would be a solution, because of the NAT).

**QUESTION(s)**

- How can I manage a scenario like this with overlapping subnets?
- How can I set a `ipsec0` interface? (I've tried with `interfaces="ipsec=eth0"` but it fails)
- In the full scenario, I have more `[R-App Servers]` connected to different `NATs` reachable from the same `[R-VPN GW]`

**DATA**
**ipsec.conf**

```
right=2.2.2.2
rightid=2.2.2.2
rightsubnet=45.2.2.2/32
rightnexthop=45.2.2.2
# Even without rightnexthop tried
rightsourceip=10.2.2.2
```

**route -n**

```
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.254      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
45.2.2.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

So, as I understand, it would be nice if I had `10.1.1.1` instead of `45.2.2.2` in the routes. I've tried to add it as my `rightsubnet`, but `ipsec` fails to bring up the tunnel.

If you need some data please comment the question. In the meaning time, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You need to re-number one side.

Comment: @EEAA thanks for your answer. Even if I re-number one side (let's say `192.168.0.0`, so my new `[R-App Server]` will be `192.168.0.2`, how I could manage the fact that the `192.168.0.2` must be routed through the VPN? I see announced only the `NAT` subnet, so only that route is pushed ... You could save my life with your answer :D. Thank you !